# Parsing a JSON document using JS

Tags: javascript, json

Here is a link

http://api.frrole.com/locations

It is returning a JSON document and i need to parse it with JS, but i dont know why i am unable to do it.

Here is my JS code to just print the count of "results" array.

```
$.get( "http://api.frrole.com/locations", function(data) {
        alert(data.results.length);
    })
    .done(function() {
        alert("done");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
        //alert( "finished" );
    });
```

But it is always alerting "error". Any suggestions why?

Comment: Probably a CORS issue.

Comment: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource...!

Comment: I think it is not. because i am apble to parse http://api.frrole.com/v1/topic JSON.

Comment: Thought you wont be able to access it because i havent mentioned the api key.

Comment: do you use chrome? you can look in the developer tools (shortcut F12) check the console for error messages. What does it say?

Comment: Or try changing the fail-function to 
.fail(function(e) { console.log(e.statusText); }) to find out what error you are receiving